# Are Apache queue requests processed FIFO or prioritized?

Tags: apache-2.2, queue

As titled. Is there an strategy/implementation in Apache to prioritize request's importance to process one request before another.

Example is in the case of PNG-interlace the most significant data (overall image view) are loaded and displayed while the rest is being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httpd does not prioritize requests. Each worker processes a request as they come in. The order they're handled in depends on the underlying thread or process subsystem.